# Fatal Error: Class 'ArticlesLatestHelper' not found in Joomla 4 module while trying to add new function

Tags: module, fatal-error, joomla-4.x

I'm testing and playing with Joomla 4 alpha.
What I tried to do is to quick-edit / modify the module Latest Article (mod_articles_latest), adding a new function.

In joomla 3.x I usually adding a new function to a module by adding it to helper.php file like this :

```
class ModNameHelper
{
    public static function myFunctionName($param1,$param2)
    { ...
```

Then I call it from the default.php like this:

```
ModNameHelper::myFunctionName($param1,$param2);
```

Now I tried to duplicate these steps with mod_articles_latest by adding myCustomFunction to ArticlesLatestHelper.php like this :

```
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_articles_latest
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2019 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Joomla\Module\ArticlesLatest\Site\Helper;

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Access\Access;
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Model\ArticlesModel;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

\JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');

/**
 * Helper for mod_articles_latest
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
abstract class ArticlesLatestHelper
{
    /**
     * Retrieve a list of article
     *
     * @param   Registry       $params  The module parameters.
     * @param   ArticlesModel  $model   The model.
     *
     * @return  mixed
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public static function getList(Registry $params, ArticlesModel $model)
    { // this is the built-in function ... }


    public static function myCustomFunction($myparam) {
}
```

and then called the function in the default.php like this

```
ArticlesLatestHelper::myCustomFunction($myparam);
```

But it returned fatal error :

```
Error: Class 'ArticlesLatestHelper' not found: Class 'ArticlesLatestHelper' not found
```

Can anybody tell me, what am I doing wrong in here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either, include that helper class on the top of your `default.php` like:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\Module\ArticlesLatest\Site\Helper\ArticlesLatestHelper;
```

Then you can use that class within your `default.php` file

Or standardly define your own variable in `mod_articles_latest.php` like:

```
$myStuffHere = ArticlesLatestHelper::myCustomFunction($myparam);
```

And then you can use the returned values of `$myStuffHere` with that variable name `in default.php`

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Zollie thanks for the help. Can you help me on this one? https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24572/class-not-found-in-joomla-4-when-using-jdate-inside-a-function Thanks